# display multiple values into autocomplete text box mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I'm trying to select first name and surname from database into a autocomplete textbox in mvc. I can select only the first name and it's working fine. I just can't concatenate the two fields and display it in the autocomplete text box. Any help is greatly appreciated

Jquery:

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Content/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetEngineers")'
        });
    });
</script>

 @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { id = "txtSearch" })
 <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

controller:

```
private DBEntityDataModel _context;

public EngineersController()
{
   _context = new DBEntityDataModel();
}

public JsonResult GetEngineers(string term)
{
    List<string> engineers;

    //This is working when I select just the firstname to be displayed
    //engineers = _context.tblEngineers.Where(e => e.FirstName.StartsWith(term) || (e.Surname.StartsWith(term)))
    //    .Select(n => n.FirstName).ToList();

    //var res = (from e in _context.tblEngineers
    //           where e.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()) || e.Surname.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())
    //           select new
    //           {
    //               e.FirstName,
    //               e.Surname
    //           }).ToList();

    var res = _context.tblEngineers.Where(e => e.FirstName.StartsWith(term) || (e.Surname.StartsWith(term)))
        .Select(n => new
        {
           label = n.FirstName + ' ' + n.Surname
        }).ToList();

    return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: What is not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: the better solution is create a Calculated Property on your model

Comment: @StephenMuecke When I use the uncommented code above, it does not return firstname and surname to the autocomplete text box. I don't get any errors.

Comment: The difference appears to be in the un-commented code you have `label = ...`

Comment: @AliBesharatinia I added this public string FullName { get { return FirstName + Surname; }} and passed n.FullName to the first commented code. It didn't work

Comment: var res = _context.tblEngineers.Where(e => e.FirstName.Contains(term.ToLower()) || e => e.surename.Contains(term.ToLower())).Select(c=>c.FullName).ToList();

Comment: doesn't work my solution?

Comment: @AliBesharatinia Actually the entity was trying to query "FullName" and couldn't as it it not part of the schema. So I selected all the values from tblEngineers into a variable and then queried the variable for the fullname.